# split text in a text file

Tags: c#, string, winforms

How can I split a text file where I have various length of sentences inside and I want to read the text file when I click to button1 on my form and take, extract words from that text file that are between start and the end of `'` character and which contains `@` symbol or `#` symbol inside the start and end of `'` character and I want to know which line is it in and output the words into the text file.

Example, lets say I have a text like

```
abc'123'@def'456''@ghi'  
abc'123'@def'#456''@ghi'123456'
```

output:

```
1st sentence @ghi  
2nd sentence #456 @ghi
```

**PS**: `@def` is not in start and end of `'` character so not in the output

I tied with split function but couldn't make it and turned into mass: ( How can I make this. I will be pleased if someone who knows helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look hard. What have you tried?

Comment: `i tied with split function but couldn't make it and turned into mass` - post your code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @bmused and @_Ashwin it was not working fine and i didn't feel fine with my code so i didn't post but i would unless i learn from it. can you please read @_GBmen post and my comments under.

Answer (score 0):

here ur input string is `s` & the string contains `@` or `#` at first index is `str`

```
    int start = s.indexOf("'");
    int end   = s.indexOf("'", start + 1);

    string str = s.SubString(start, end);

    if(str.ToCharArray()[0] == "@" || str.ToCharArray()[0] == "#")
        // proceed
```

Comment: i could not make it run problem and i think it will not work as expected. problem with if(str.ToCharArray()[0] == "@" || str.ToCharArray()[0] == "#") line  after correcting s.indexOf  to s.IndexOf kinda errors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as this example is concerned here is a sample code that works

```
      string sen1="abc'123'@def'456''@ghi'";
      string sen2 = "abc'123'@def'#456''@ghi'123456'";

      string[] NewSen = Regex.Split(sen1, "''");

      string YourFirstOP=NewSen[1].ToString(); //gets @ghi


      NewSen = Regex.Split(sen2, "''");

      string[] A1 = Regex.Split(NewSen[0], "'");
      string[] A2 = Regex.Split(NewSen[1], "'");


      string YourSecondOP= A1[A1.Length - 1] + "" + A2[A2.Length - 3].ToString();// gets #456 @ghi
```

But thats just this example

Hope this helps

Comment: your solution is not generic will not work with a various length string. but thanks for the effort. actually i thank to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

```
string [] Mass = s.Split('\'');
if (Mass.Length > 1)
    for (int i = 1; i < (Mass.Length - 1); i += 2)
    {
          if (Mass[i].Contains("@") || Mass[i].Contains("#"))
           // proceed
    }
```

Comment: this will find match in text like `@123'def` also

Comment: @Damith  you are wrong it works BUT instead of using  if (Mass[i].StartsWith("@") || Mass[i].StartsWith("#"))   if we use   if (Mass[i].Contains("@") || Mass[i].Contains("#"))  it work perfect because then it will return the # and @ character containing words between the start and the end of ' character. else it will only return the # and @ character starting words.

Comment: @GBmen beside the issue i stated above it works correct. comment out the if statement you wrote and add a new line with  if (Mass[i].Contains("@") || Mass[i].Contains("#"))   and i will accept you answer. thanks.

Comment: @GBmen by the way i want to read from a text file (because strings are there line by line) and out put the results into an another text file like i stated in my question. can you provide a solution for this? thanks.

Comment: You can use TextReader and TextWriter classes of System.IO namespase. To read strings use method TextReader.ReadLine() and to write strings use method TextWriter.WriteLine(). I hope its helpful, and sorry for English.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string testString = @"abc'123'@def'456''@ghi'abc'123'@def'#456''@ghi'123456'";
List<string> output = new List<string>();
int startIndex = 0;
int endIndex = 0;

while (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex >= 0)
{
    startIndex = testString.IndexOf("'", endIndex + 1);
    endIndex = testString.IndexOf("'", startIndex + 1);
    if (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex >= 0)
    {
        string str = testString.Substring(startIndex + 1, (endIndex - startIndex) - 1);                     
        int indexOfSpecialChar = str.IndexOf("@");
        if (indexOfSpecialChar < 0)
        {
            indexOfSpecialChar = str.IndexOf("#");
        }

        if (indexOfSpecialChar >= 0)
        {
            output.Add(str.Substring(indexOfSpecialChar));
        }
    }
}
```